# __attribute__((packed)) vs #pragma pack(push, 1) give different size of structure

Tags: c++

I tried `__attribute__((packed))` and `#pragma pack(push, 1)` on the same structure but I'm getting different sizes.

I'm based on x64 machine.

OS: Linux and VxWorks

Code :

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct 
{
    std::uint8_t    num1;
    std::uint16_t   num2;
    std::uint32_t   num3;
    float           num4;
}transmit1_t __attribute__((packed));

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct 
{
    std::uint8_t    num1;
    std::uint16_t   num2;
    std::uint32_t   num3;
    float           num4;
}transmit_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "transmit_t size : " << sizeof(transmit_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "transmit1_t size : " << sizeof(transmit1_t) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
transmit_t size : 11
transmit1_t size : 12
```

---

Compiler :

1. gcc-12 on Linux
2. Clang 16 on VxWorks

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/x4dq7ox64  `warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]`  You have the wrong order. `__attribute__((packed)) transmit1_t;` is what you want.

Comment: When you ask about non-standard compiler-specific functionality please also always mention which compiler you are asking about.